# How to calculate distance required for stopping object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

Object `A` is moving via. `2D rigidbody` by velocity `V` and in script is defined breaking power `P`. Every frame of breaking (`P` * Time.deltaTime) is subtracted from velocity `V` (in other words, ignoring mass). How i can calculate distance required to slow down to target velocity `tV` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a kinematics (physics) question, and is not programming-specific.

Comment: Refer to [Stopping Distance (frictionless)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3818/stopping-distance-frictionless) for the answer.

Comment: I must opposite you @Serlite . Physics, math and programming are very close to each other and frequently is required cooperation of all three categories in order to complete given task. This is exactly related to AI so it is game dev question. Only reason, why i'm asking this question is because i was born with asperger's syndrome so i was in special class where they didn't teach us advanced mathematics like this.

Comment: Sorry to hear about your condition, but there are rules about asking we must adhere to in order to make sure that the content is on-topic. Programming is by no means related to physics, and is only related to math through very fundamental concepts, which do not include calculus and kinematics. This particular problem can be solved using calculus and basic physics concepts alone, without using any programming languages  or axioms.

Answer (score 2):

You have a defined rate of decreasing velocity (P * delta) so you know how long it's gonna take to slow down. The formula for distance when velocity is changing linearly is s = 0.5 * a * t^2, that's gonna be the slowing down portion, that would be total distance if you slowed down to zero. Since you'll have a remaining speed, you also have to account for it: s = v*t. You add those.

The math involved might make more sense to you if you consider this scenario going backwards: you move at 10m/s and accelerate to 20m/s. The distance would have two portions, the one from the initial speed as if you werent accelerating = v0*t, and then the portion you get from accelerating = 0.5*a*t^2.

So the complete formula is s = v0*t + 0.5*a*t^2.
v0 is initial speed, t is time it takes to change speed, a is the acceleration/deceleration rate. In case of decelerating, v0 is the target speed.

For example, if you wanted to slow down from 20m/s to 10/ms with breaking 2m/s^2, it would take you 5 seconds. The slowing down distance would be 0.5 * 2 * 25 = 25 meters. This would be slowing down from 10m/s to 0. Since you have 10m/s left, you add 5 * 10 = 50 meters. Total distance would be 75 meters.

Comment: Thanks but what "^2" means ?